# Using $this when not in object context error within array_walk

Tags: php

I am experiencing an odd problem with using `array_walk` with closures within a class. The problem does not arise within my development environment using php version **5.4.7** but it does on my deployment environment **5.3.3**.

The following code runs fine on my production box, but crashes on my deployment environment:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);

    Class TestArrayWalk
    {
        /** @var null|array */
        protected $userInput = null;

        /**
         * This expects to be passed an array of the users input from
         * the input fields.
         *
         * @param  array $input
         * @return void
         */
        public function setUserInput( array $input )
        {
            $this->userInput = $input;

            // Lets explode the users input and format it in a way that this class
            // will use for marking
            array_walk( $this->userInput, function( &$rawValue )
                {
                    $rawValue = array(
                        'raw' => $rawValue,
                        'words' => $this->splitIntoKeywordArray( $rawValue ),
                        'marked' => false,
                        'matched' => array()
                    );
                }
            );
        }

        public function getUserInput()
        {
            return $this->userInput;
        }

        protected function splitIntoKeywordArray( $input )
        {
            if ( ! is_string( $input )){ return array(); }
            return preg_split('/(\s|[\.,\/:;!?])/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        }

    }


    $testArrayWalk = new TestArrayWalk();
    $testArrayWalk->setUserInput(
            array(
                'This is a test input',
                'This is another test input'
                )
        );

    var_dump( $testArrayWalk->getUserInput() );
```

The error I am getting is: `Using $this when not in object context on line 26` which is the only usage of `$this` within that test class. I am assuming something changed between the versions I am using that has made the above code possible in my development environment.

I also assume that as I cant change the deployment environment (its the clients and they wont change it) that I am going to have to use a `foreach` rather than `array_walk`.

**My question is this:** Given the above, is this possible in 5.3.3 using `array_walk` if not how do I use `foreach` in the same way that I am using array_walk ( more specifically the `&$rawValue` bit)?

My environments are:

- My development environment is PHP version **5.4.7**
- My server (deployment) environment is PHP version **5.3.3**

Thanks.

**Edit 2**

Thanks to everyone who helped. With your help I got this working and have posted my working code to https://gist.github.com/carbontwelve/6727555 for future reference.

Comment: Just a `foreach($this->userInput as &$rawValue){` would suffice at quick glance (remember to `unset($rawValue);` after the loop). [according to this codepad thing, it works](http://codepad.org/hpAof4kV)

Comment: Oh, [and this mentions (PHP 5.4 changelog)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php): _"Closures now support $this."_, so a version problem indeed.

Comment: try with error_reporting(2048) in both environment and see whether error shows up in both. If so, it could be due to the error reporting behaviour change between 5.3 and 5.4

Comment: Wrikken is entirely correct, support for `$this` in closures was only added in PHP 5.4 - server version does not support that.

Comment: @Wrikken thank you. I am still getting my head around pointers in PHP and had replaced all my `foreach` loops with `array_walk` so I could take advantage of anonymous functions. I knew it was possible with `foreach` but at the time had it "working" with array_walk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is described in PHP manual:

```
Version Description
5.4.0   $this can be used in anonymous functions.
```

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Possible workaround would be to re-assign this to another variable and pass it via `use`:

```
$_this = $this;
function() use($_this) { ... }
```

but keep in mind you will not be able to access private and protected members so you will have to make `splitIntoKeywordArray` public

Answer (score 1):

You may also use if you are using `PHP < 5.4`

```
public function setUserInput( array $input )
{
    $this->userInput = $input;
    $userInput_array = &$this->userInput;
    array_walk( &$userInput_array, function( &$rawValue ) use (&$userInput_array) {
        // use $userInput_array instaed of $this->userInput_array
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a lambda function defined in a private function within a class:

```
MyClass{
    private $str="doesn't work :-(";
    private function foo(){
        $bar=function(){
            echo $this->str; // triggers an "Using $this when not in object context" error
        };
        $bar();
    }
}
```

> **Solution for PHP 5.3.0**: declare a variable $obj=&$this in your parent scope (ie. the private function) and pass it to the anonymouse function by using the `use` language construct. Also make sure the function/variable that you access has a `public` visibility (protected|private might not work).

```
MyClass{
    public $str="it just works :-)";
    private function foo(){
        $obj=&$this;
        $bar=function() use(&$obj){
            echo $this->str; // it works!
        };
        $bar();
    }
}
```